# Insightful educational games about physics?

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, big-list

I came across this game called "[a slower speed of light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43695/how-realistic-is-the-game-a-slower-speed-of-light)". I don't know whether it is officially an "educational game" (I haven't played it), but it is about the effects of special relativity.

This made me wonder whether there are more **games about physics that can serve as** **an intuitive supplement to the mathematics for someone who is learning physics**. (I'm not saying they can be a substitute for understanding the mathematics, just a supplement).

I've seen some lists online with games about physics, but there seem to be a lot of low quality ones.

So my idea was to create a **list of (educational) video games that successfully and insightfully convey counter-intuitive physical phenomena like in relativity and quantum mechanics,** which one can use alongside a formal training in physics.

- Simple games for children or simple Newtonian games about spaceships in zero-gravity don't suffice. The games have to be about "relatively advanced" ideas such as relativity, or quantum mechanics.
- The games don't have to be officially "educational", so long as they insightfully capture such a physical phenomenon.
- My intention is not to use them as substitutes for, but as a complement to formal physics training, i.e. as a way to boost intuition for someone who also studies the topic formally.

Comment: You can try playing velocity raptor [here](http://testtubegames.com/velocityraptor.html). idk if thats what you are looking for, I found the game interesting!

Comment: Has to be so specific as a slower speed of light? There are some applications that I found not bad. Or quite some about astronomy and even space flights.  Orbiter is a free orbital flying simulatir.. Not for children, I would say.  I think by using the search words of relevance you can find something of your interest.

Comment: Although I haven't played, [Kerbal Space Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerbal_Space_Program) is highly praised for its realistic orbital mechanics.

Comment: Yep KSP is cool.

Comment: To those vtc'ing as "too broad" I believe this does fit within resource recommendation policies, especially due to the specificity of the *type* of resource - there aren't really that many truly rigorous physics-oriented video games.